# Find maximum value in associative array

Tags: php

I have a associative array:

```
$users[0] = array('name' => 'Jim', 'depth' => '1', 'bk_id' => '9'); 
$users[1] = array('name' => 'Jill', 'depth' => '3', 'bk_id' => '10'); 
$users[2] = array('name' => 'Jack', 'depth' => '7', 'bk_id' => '17');
```

I would like to know a way of finding the array index with the maximum or greatest depth value?

Any suggestion is most appreciated.

Comment: This is PHP code, not JavaScript or jQuery. Tag added.

Comment: Are you asking about finding the data you want *Using JS after that data structure has been encoded to JSON then parsed by JS* or *Using PHP without involving JS or JSON in any way*?

Comment: I would like the data to be returned in JS

Comment: Then I still have no idea what the question is but have an uncanny feeling that it falls into the category of "Overly broad". I suggest you revise it so you are asking about one specific thing that you are stuck on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just iterate and look at the maximum value:

```
var max = 0, maxIndex = -1;
for(var i=0;i<users.length;i++) {
   if(parseInt(users[i].depth,10) > max) {
      max = users[i].depth;
      maxIndex = i;
   }
}
console.log("Your maximum depth is %d at index %d", max, maxIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is unclear, here's how to find it with PHP.

```
foreach ($users as $index => $user) {
  if (!isset($maxdepth)) {
    $maxdepth = $user['depth'];
    $maxindex = $index;
  }
  else {
    if ($user['depth']) > $maxdepth) {
       $maxindex = $index;
       $maxdepth = $user['depth'];
    }
}
echo "Index: $maxindex";
```

Comment: The OP claims to be looking for the _index_ of the record with the maximum depth.

Answer (score 1):

From PHP:

```
$index = 0;
$max = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($users); $i++) {
    if ($users[$i]['depth'] > $max) {
        $max = $users[$i]['depth'];
        $index = $i;
    }
}

echo $users[$index]['name'] . ' has the greatest depth.';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either iterate over all the key-value pairs looking at the depth value each time, or sort the `$users` array using a custom sort function like `sort_func(){ return a.depth - b.depth}`

Answer (score 0):

Using native sort function?

```
function getDeepestItem(arr)
{
    arr.sort(function(a,b){return a['depth'] < b['depth'];});
    return arr[0]
}
```